# how to provide .jad file download link?

Tags: java, blackberry, jad

We are trying to provide a download link to abc.jad file in index.html. abc.jad and index.html are both in the same folder. Following is the link.

```
<a href="abc.jad" type="text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor">download</a>
```

In spite of these, we are still not able to download this file from the web browser. It always gives the error HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found .what can i do for that Problem? please any one give me the solution .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a webserver configuration error to me, and nothing to do with Blackberrys or JADs.

If you can't download a file using a web browser, you need to check out your web server.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is likely a server configuration issue, it is possible that the device is requesting additional files that do not exist.

A JAD file is a Java Application Descriptor (JAD) that J2ME (CLDC/MIDP) applications use to describe the Java modules associated with an application. In the case of BlackBerry applications, a JAD describes a collection of COD files that represent the compiled version of your application. The BlackBerry RAPC compiler compiles to a single COD file, but this file typically contains a collection of other COD files when your application becomes large enough.

Try performing these steps:

- Open application COD in archive application (WinZip, WinRAR, 7-zip, etc)
- Extract all COD files in application COD to same directory as JAD file
- Attempt to download JAD file

Comment: At least in the version of the Eclipse plugin that I'm using it automatically splits the application into multiple COD files.  In the output directory (which is named "deliverables" by default) there will be two subdirectories, one named "Standard" and one named "Web".  The directory called "Web" will contain multiple COD files if necessary, the directory called "Standard" will just have one large COD file.